# Rails 3 company account with many users, restrict access to data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, access-control, user-permissions

I'm wondering about the best way to structure authentication/authorization in my app. I want to have

- many company accounts, possibly using subdomains
- account has many users
- and users can only access records that were created by themselves or another user with the same account.

The research I've done provides lots of mix n' match ideas for combining devise / cancan / authlogic in weird and wonderful ways, but I've yet to find anything which shows me the best way to restrict user access to data within the same model.

So for instance:

---

Account 1: Eurasia

User 1: Bob

User 2: Jim

---

Account 2: Eastasia

User 1: Dave

User 2: Alan

---

Isbn 1: account_id is 1

Isbn 2: account_id is 2

---

How do I make sure Bob can't access or crud Isbn 2?

///update
Of course, now I've posted this, my google fu has kicked in and I've found the readme from RyanB for [CanCan 2.0](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/CanCan-2.0), which seems perfect:

### > Resources

> What if you need to change authorization based on a model's
>   attributes? You can do so by passing a hash of conditions as the last
>   argument to can. For example, if you want to only allow one to access
>   projects which he owns you can set the :user_id option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization.

Your Ability model would look something like

```
can :manage, :isbn do |isbn|
  isbn.account == current_user.account
end
```

Then you can use conditionals like `can? :manage, @post` in your Controller/Views.

Comment: Ah, right, ta. So there'd be an account attribute in Isbn, and if the current user == 1, the user could access that record. Have I got that right? That seems too good to be true!

Comment: hmm, there I get for not having worked with CanCan that much. Nice, will probably check it out for my next project :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization I think that one do exactly as you're asking for (you can limit access to certain records)

so, in your example you could set up the authorization with something like this:

```
has_permission_on :isbn do 
    to :manage
    if_attribute :account_id => is_in {user.account_ids}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at XACML? It's a policy-based, declarative framework for authorization. It's also a standard from OASIS.

With XACML you can take any attributes you need (user, resource, action, or context attributes) and express the use case that you have.

Your initial requirement was

> users can only access records that were created by themselves or another user with the same account.

In XACML that would become the following policy:

> A user can access a record if and only if the record.owner==user.id OR
>   user.accountId==record.accountId

That's all! XACML's architecture defines the policy enforcement point (PEP) which is the component that protects your app/data and sends the authorization request to the policy decision point (PDP). 
The PEP says: "Can Alice access record #123?"
The PDP checks Alice's account Id and the record's account id as well as owner.
The PDP eventually returns a "Permit" or a "Deny".

HTH