# all queries default to users company

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

I am using cancan and trying to get it to limit equipment shown for a specific company.

I have a company with many users that should only see equipment that belong to that company.

I thought cancan could do this based on this:

[Rails 3 company account with many users, restrict access to data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655275/rails-3-company-account-with-many-users-restrict-access-to-data)

So I tried this code:

```
can :manage, Equipment do |equipment|
  user.company == equipment.company
end
```

In the equipment controller I have `@equipment = Equipment.all` which I figured would just pull the equipment for that users company, but of course it pulls them all.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to do `@equipment = Equipment.find_by_company_id(current_user.company)` anytime I want to pull just that companies equipment.  To make this worse I want to eventually break it down by groups and departments, but would rather not have to force myself into more big find queries.  I am open to anything, plugins, suggestions, whatever will be the fastest way to fix this.

I could have added more code to this question, but I don't know that adding it all would really help the question.

Thank you very much

Toby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Equipment.accessible_by()`

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/model_additions.rb

Comment: This is what I get when I try that: `The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition. The SQL cannot be determined for :index

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite your definition without a block, like this:  `can :manage, Equipment, :company => user.company`